# invalid input syntax for integer (Netsjs)

Tags: nestjs

In nestjs I created the following endpoint and when I hit it form swagger or postman return

invalid input syntax for integer: "NaN"

```js
  @Get('creatives-by-ids')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  getCreativeByIds(@GetCurrentUser() user: CurrentUser, @Query() ids: number[]) {
    return [];
  }
```

Comment: What's the stack trace you're dealing with? Where is it trying to use an integer incorrectly?

Comment: I don't use anything I make endpoint simple as possible to figure out why this error occur so now the endpoint to doesn't anything else return empty array as I write in question

Comment: Something is throwing an error somewhere, right? Can you show the full error that's being logged in the console? And possibly a sample request?

Answer (score 3):

I met the same issue recently and it turned out that it was due to the sequence of routes, which is not specific to Nest.js but generally for express.js. Your trouble might be the same as mine.

```js
  @Get(':id')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  getCreativeById(@GetCurrentUser() user: CurrentUser, @Param('id') id: number) {
    return [];
  }

  @Get('creatives-by-ids')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  getCreativeByIds(@GetCurrentUser() user: CurrentUser, @Query() ids: number[]) {
    return [];
  }
```

If my assumtion is correct, you probably have `GET(':id')` just like above or similar.
In this case, latter one(`@Get('creatives-by-ids')`) is ignored, because the former one takes the priority and 'creatives-by-ids' is regarded as a param.

So the solution is to adjust the sequence of routes properly, moving the latter one up above the `GET(':id')`.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution for this problem:

```
@Get(':id') -> @Get('/:id')
```